# avoid auto escape in html template

Tags: go, go-html-template

Trying to render HTML template with an URL. The problem is that the URL contains () in it, and those characters are escaped.

I tried to use `template.URL("http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg")` and also `template.HTML("http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg")` but it still escape brackets.

I'm using [gin gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#html-rendering).

```
router.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "test.tmpl", gin.H{
        "url": template.URL("http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg"),
        // "url": template.HTML("http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg"),
})
```

Template file :

```
<div>
  <img src="{{.url}}" />
</div>
```

final ouput :

```
<div>
  <img src="http://myurl.com/%28data%29/aaa.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a value of [`template.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#URL) is perfectly enough.

What you see is **not** HTML encoding of the given URL, what you see is the URL encoding of the opening and closing parenthesis in the `(data)` part. That is perfectly ok. `%28` is the encoding of `'('` (28 is the hexa code for the opening parenthesis character), and `%29` is the `')'` character.

The url `http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg` and `http://myurl.com/%28data%29/aaa.jpg` are one and the same.

The purpose of the URL encoding is so that URLs and values included in URLs (e.g. form parameters) can be safely transmitted.

> **URL Encoding**
>
> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
>   URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

You can read more about URL encoding here: [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Testing it:

```
func rh(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, `<html><body>
<img src="http://localhost:8080/(data)/aaa.jpg">
<img src="http://localhost:8080/%28data%29/aaa.jpg">
</body></htm>`)
}

func imgh(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "aaa.jpg")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", rh)
    http.HandleFunc("/(data)/aaa.jpg", imgh)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}
```

Now direct your browser to `http://localhost:8080`. It will display 2 images.

Comment: `http://myurl.com/%28data%29/aaa.jpg` can't be reach and responses 404 while `http://myurl.com/(data)/aaa.jpg` display the jpg file.

Comment: Your test works, but you serve an image to `/(data)/aaa.jpg`. However I need to pass the entire URL (since it's from a CDN) to my template. And strangely `%28` and `%29` are not understand as `(` and `)`...

Comment: @Jérôme Note that the html page contains 2 images, and the 2nd has the  source attribute `src="http://localhost:8080/%28data%29/aaa.jpg"` (that is, parenthesis are encoded), and this works too, the 2nd image is also displayed.