# Prevent escaping forward slashes in templates

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I'm working on converting a pet project of mine from Python to Go just to help me get a bit familiar with the language. An issue I am currently facing is that it's escaping my forward slashes. So it will receive a string like:

```
/location/to/something
```

and it then becomes

```
%2flocation%2fto%2fsomething
```

Now, it's only doing this when it's in a link (from what I've been reading this escaping is contextual) so this is what the line in the HTML template looks like:

```
<tr><td><a href="/file?file={{.FullFilePath}}">{{.FileName}}</a></td></tr>
```

If possible, how can I prevent this in either the template or the code itself?

This is what my templating function looks like (yes, I know it's hackish)

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(templates_dir+"base.html", templates_dir+tmpl)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    if tmpl == "view.html" {
        err = t.Execute(w, FileList)
    } else {
        err = t.Execute(w, nil)
    }
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [avoid auto escape in html template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980049/avoid-auto-escape-in-html-template)

Comment: @icza, thanks for referring me to that link but I can't see how I can implement that solution here. I'm admittedly still a noob so perhaps that's why. I did end up finding another question whose solution ended up helping me so I've posted that here.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the value of `.FullFilePath`, pass a value of type [`template.URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#URL) instead of `string`, which will tell the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package not to escape it.

For example:

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))

    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "FileName":     "something.txt",
        "FileFullPath": template.URL("/location/to/something"),
    }

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `<tr><td><a href="/file?file={{.FileFullPath}}">{{.FileName}}</a></td></tr>`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/om2dyE-Z-W)):

```
<tr><td><a href="/file?file=/location/to/something">something.txt</a></td></tr>
```

Note that even though forward slashes `/` are allowed in URLs, the reason why the `template` package still encodes them is because it analyses the URL and sees that the value you want to include is the value of a URL parameter (`file=XXX`), and so it also encodes the slashes (so that everything you pass in will be part of the value of the `file` URL parameter).

If you plan to acquire this file path at the server side from URL parameters, then what the `template` package does is the correct and proper way.

But know that by doing this, you'll lose the safety that prevents code injection into URLs. If you're the one providing the values and you know they are safe, there is no problem. But if the data comes from a user input for example, never do this.

Also note that if you pass the whole URL (and not just a part of it), it will work without using `template.URL` (try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sKji20On0_)):

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))

    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "FileName": "something.txt",
        "FileURL":  "/file?file=/location/to/something",
    }

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `<tr><td><a href="{{.FileURL}}">{{.FileName}}</a></td></tr>`
```

Also note that the recommended way in my opinion would be to include the file path as part of the URL path and not as the value of a parameter, so instead you should create urls like this:

```
/file/location/to/something
```

Map your handler (which serves the file content, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899786/1705598) as an example) to the `/file/` pattern, and when it is matched and your handler is called, cut off the `/file/` prefix from the path `r.URL.Path`, and the rest will be the full file path. If you choose this, you also won't need the `template.URL` conversion (because the value you include is not a value of a URL parameter anymore):

```
func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))

    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "FileName":     "something.txt",
        "FileFullPath": "/location/to/something",
    }

    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

const templ = `<tr><td><a href="/file{{.FileFullPath}}">{{.FileName}}</a></td></tr>`
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VTxDasztY7).

Also very important: never parse templates in your handler functions! For details see:

[It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p)

Comment: Thanks, this is much appreciated. Thanks for explaining the security risks involved, in my case it's not applicable (this is just something I use at home, not public facing) but it's useful for others to know.

Comment: @basica Also see the note added to the end: never parse templates in the handler functions (it's slow, and should be done prior to calling handlers).

Comment: Unfortunately this technique doesn't seem to work in JavaScript on* handlers, like onclick: https://play.golang.org/p/E_TU3xPAq6s

Comment: Looks like there is an easy workaround lol: https://play.golang.org/p/d0l9Pb26oqT

Comment: FYI: the above workaround which works on play.golang.org doesn't work on my server: a space is inserted between "o" and "nclick". Sill looking for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So the solution I've found (and please post if there's a better one) is based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765395/why-am-i-seeing-zgotmplz-in-my-go-html-template-output).

I changed the struct I was using from:

```
type File struct {
    FullFilePath string
    FileName     string
}
```

To this:

```
type File struct {
    FullFilePath template.HTML
    FileName     string
}
```

And moved the html into the FullFilePath name, and then placed that in template.HTML so each FullFilePath name I was generating was done like so:

```
file := File{template.HTML("<a href=\"/file?file=" + path + "\"</a>"), f.Name()}
```

And my template file line was changed to this:

```
<tr><td>{{.FullFilePath}}{{.FileName}}</td></tr>
```